# How to make empty values have a default value?

Tags: laravel

Im trying to give model attribute values another value when they are blank,
At the moment this is what I'm working with in my model:

```
public function getAttribute($property){
    if(blank($this->attributes[$property])){
        return $this->attributes[$property] = '-';
    }else{
        return $this->attributes[$property];
    }
}
```

It works, but I dont think this is the right way to do it.

Im looking for a proper way of doing this.

example:

lets say the value in the database is NULL,
I want it to show "-" when displaying, but I dont want to save "-" in the database.
(I also don't want to use "get...Value" mutators for every value)

Comment: Depends on where you're going to display the data I guess. You could use `{{ $model->attribute ?? '-' }}` in views, but I don't know if that solves your problem?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan This works, but I would still have to add it every time I want to display a value, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: [Default Attribute Values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#default-attribute-values)

Comment: @Namoshek That is not the solution, because that would be saved to the database, which xVivio doesn't want.

Comment: @DouwedeHaan You are right, I overlooked the last paragraph. Upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution 1

Since PHP 7 there is a new feature called the [Null Coalescing operator](https://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op). It returns the first operator when it exists and is not `NULL`:

```
{{ $model->attribute ?? '-' }}
```

Which is the same as this:

```
{{ isset($model->attribute) ? $model->attribute : '-' }}
```

## Solution 2

Another solution would be a little bit harder, but doable:

Create a base model to which you extend all the other models:

```
class BaseModel extends Model {

    protected $emptyAttributes = [];

    protected function getAttribute($property)
    {
        if (in_array($property, $this->emptyAttributes) && blank($this->attributes[$property])) {
            return '-';
        }
        else {
            return $this->attributes[$property];
        }
    }
}
```

Now extend all the models you want to this new class and create an array of 'attributes to replace':

```
class User extends BaseModel {

    protected $emptyAttributes = ['name', 'email'];

}
```

This should automatically replace the attributes `name` and `email` when they are empty, NULL or a string of only spaces.

Side note:
You could also move the functionality to a trait (which could be a more elegant solution, but that's up to you).

Comment: This works, but I would still have to add it every time I want to display a value, which is not what I'm looking for. Also, If the value is " ", I still want to display "-".
Laravel has a function for this, "blank()", I made this function which I used at first, but I decided against using it after `function replaceBlank($string, $replacement = '-')
{
   if(blank($string)){
        return $replacement;
   }
   return $string;
}`

Comment: @xVivio I added an alternative solution. Your solution would work as well and can even be made into a blade directive.